# How do I deconflict multiple ABRecord when the uniqueid fails and I have people with the same first and last name?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, addressbook

This may be down in the weeds, but thought I'd throw this out there and ask. So I'm building an app where I need to reference information in the address book, say a person's phone number, but do not want to store the info separately. Basically, every time the user loads the app, I'll go check the address book and get the info just in case they've updated it.

Anyway, I've read this in the iPhone Programming Doc:

> "Every record in the Address Book database has a unique record identifier. This identifier always refers to the same record, unless that record is deleted or the MobileMe sync data is reset. Record identifiers can be safely passed between threads. They are not guaranteed to remain the same across devices.
>
> The recommended way to keep a long-term reference to a particular record is to store the first and last name, or a hash of the first and last name, in addition to the identifier. When you look up a record by ID, compare the record’s name to your stored name. If they don’t match, use the stored name to find the record, and store the new ID for the record."

So what I'm worried about or curious about is let's say I've stored the uids and the first and last name. Then let's say upon sync or device transfer or whatever my uids get hosed. Now let's say my address book contains two entries for user "Bob Smith".

How do you deconflict this given the uids no longer match and first/last name are the same? My guess is to end up storing other info (e.g. phone number, email, etc...) but that puts me back into the situation of not really wanting to store more info than is necessary. I'm realizing this could be a .0001% time problem, but thought I'd throw this out there to see what you all thought.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

I’m trying to solve the same problem. But with my solution, I can (or actually need to) store everything for multi-platform/multi-device issues. But if you can afford to pick up one or two additional properties to really find the difference between the two people (lets say e-mail address and birthday date), you should be able to recognize them at most times. If not, I would wonder if they aren’t really the same person (same name, same e-mail, same birthday… walks like a duck, quacks like a duck, is duck enough).

And I would say, it’s not .0001 % time, ie. me and my father have the very same name (and that happens to a lot of people in my country). But we definitely don’t have the same e-mail address or birthday date.